# Choreographer Null Pointer Exception

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Component used: Version used: 1.2.1 Devices/Android versions reproduced on: Android 12

We are facing this crash on **Android 12** devices with manufacturer **Oppo, Oneplus and Realme** Suddenly we started seeing these variety of crashes related to **Choreographer** in logs of Firebase crashlytics.

Unable to find any solution , If anyone is familiar with this issue, your help would be greatly appreciated.
``

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$p androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.mLayout' on a null object reference in method 'int androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$z.getChildCount()'
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$SmoothScroller.getChildCount(RecyclerView.java:12361)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearSmoothScroller.onSeekTargetStep(LinearSmoothScroller.java:127)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$SmoothScroller.onAnimation(RecyclerView.java:12337)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$ViewFlinger.run(RecyclerView.java:5564)
       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1232)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:1029)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:925)
       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1217)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:233)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:344)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8212)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:584)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1034)
```

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.getChildLayoutPosition(android.view.View)' on a null object reference
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$SmoothScroller.getChildPosition(RecyclerView.java:12354)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$SmoothScroller.onChildAttachedToWindow(RecyclerView.java:12381)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.addViewInt(RecyclerView.java:8905)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.addView(RecyclerView.java:8860)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.addView(RecyclerView.java:8848)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1645)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1591)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.scrollBy(LinearLayoutManager.java:1395)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.scrollHorizontallyBy(LinearLayoutManager.java:1124)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.scrollStep(RecyclerView.java:1969)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$SmoothScroller.onAnimation(RecyclerView.java:12316)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$ViewFlinger.run(RecyclerView.java:5564)
       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1232)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:1029)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:925)
       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1217)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:233)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:344)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8212)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:584)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1034)
```

As i have been using recycler-view 1.2.1 version i.e latest one , as crash is happening in component itself, Google issue tracker link https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/252707877